# SQL calculate producibles with shared components

Tags: sql-server, subquery, common-table-expression

I'm trying to figure out how many products we can produce based on the components on stock and the structure of these products.

Tables look like this (dummy data):

__STOCKALMART:

```
Codart       Codalm    Unidades
BlisterS       1         100
BoxB           1         100
BoxB           2         50
Article1       3         150
BoxY           2         120
Article2       3         120
BoxG           2         100
Article3       3         20
```

escandallo:

```
Codartp   codartc    UNICOMPO
PA1       Article1      1
PA1       BlisterS      1
PA1       BoxB          1
PA2       Article2      1
PA2       BlisterS      1
PA2       BoxY          1
PA3       Article3      1
PA3       BlisterS      1
PA3       BoxG          1
```

Some products share components (some of them more than 1): BlisterS

Now, I managed to calculate the producible quantity of products without taking in count these shared components. This is my query:

```
with cit as -- component inventory total
(
  select s.codart,
         sum(s.unidades) as unidades
  from __STOCKALMART s
  where s.codalm not in (9999)
  group by s.codart
),
pci as -- product component inventory
(
  select e.codartp,
         cit.unidades / e.unicompo as maxPart
  from escandallo e
  join cit
    on cit.codart = e.codartc
    where e.unicompo >= 1
)
select  trim(l.codart) SKU, 
        isnull(sum(l.unidades - l.unianulada - l.uniservida),0) as "SO Pending",
        (select isnull(sum(stk.unidades),0) 
           from __STOCKALMART stk 
          where stk.codart = l.codart 
            and stk.CODALM not in (9999)) as "STOCK",
        case when isnull(sum(l.unidades - l.unianulada - l.uniservida),0) - 
            (select isnull(sum(stk.unidades),0) 
               from __STOCKALMART stk 
              where stk.codart = l.codart 
                and stk.CODALM not in (9999)) < 0
            then 0 else isnull(sum(l.unidades - l.unianulada - l.uniservida),0) - 
                        (select isnull(sum(stk.unidades),0) 
                           from __STOCKALMART stk 
                          where stk.codart = l.codart 
                            and stk.CODALM not in (9999)) end as "to produce",
        min(pci.maxpart) as producible
from linepedi l
join pci on pci.codartp = l.codart
where l.codart in (select codartp from escandallo where codartc like 'Article%')
and l.unidades - l.unianulada - l.uniservida > 0
and l.comven = 'v'
group by l.codart
order by l.codart
```

That query returns something like this:

```
SKU     SO Pending       STOCK       to produce       producible
PA1         450           340           110             100   --there are only 100 blisterS
PA2         1000          2000          0               100   --there are only 100 blisterS
PA3         250           240           10              20    --there are only 20 Article3
```

I'd like to reduce this info to "To produce" and "producible", grouped in a single row, taking in count that they're sharing components and limiting the producible with the "to produce". The result table would look like this:

```
to produce    producible
   120           100
```

Is this feasible? Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you very much

Comment: Firstly please only ask a single question per question. Secondly "Is there any book or course I can take to improve my subqueries skills?" is not a suitable question for this site.

Comment: @DaleK ok, I edited the post with what I have and what I'd like to achieve